# Java - Stream is closed

Tags: java, exception

I am running another jar with this code:
(I am updating a gui in some parts , so dont feel confused.)I get an IO Exception (Stream Closed) here:

```
if((line = readr.readLine()) != null){
```

Thats the full code:

```
if(!data.serverStarted()){


        try{
            data.updateConsole("Starting server!");
            String fileDir = data.dir + File.separator + "craftbukkit.jar";
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -Xmx2048M -jar "+"craftbukkit.jar"+" -o true --nojline");
            data.setOutputStream(proc.getOutputStream());
            InputStream is = proc.getErrorStream();
        }catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader readr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        data.setServerStarted(true);
        String line;
        while(data.serverStarted()){
            try {
                if((line = readr.readLine()) != null){
                    data.updateConsole(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                try {
                    readr.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        data.updateConsole("You have already started your server!");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `while` loop that closes `readr` on every pass. The next time it gets to the `try` block, `readr` is closed. Perhaps you intended to put the `try/catch` block around the `while` loop?

Comment: I'm happy to add corrections to any actual problems if the downvoter would bother to comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the reader inside the loop that reads from it. You need to close it outside of the loop:

```
try {        
    String line;
    while (data.serverStarted() && ((line = readr.readLine()) != null)) {
        try {
            data.updateConsole(line);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
} finally {
    try {
        readr.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that this code even compiles.

You declare the actual InputStream `is` inside the try/catch at the beginning, but that makes it only visible inside that block. So whatever you give to the BufferedReader a few lines below is something else and most likely not what you think it is.

In addition your `while(data.serverStarted())` does not check if the stream is still open, and later you only use a single `if` check (again with no check if the stream is open), so you'll only read one single line at best.

I have a feeling that you had a bad OutOfCoffeeException while writing this code. ;)